# IIS Error from event viewer

Tags: iis, iis-7, event-viewer

IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE

```
IIS Manager could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.DelegationModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35' for module provider 'DelegationManagement_Current' that is declared in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
at Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.AdministrationModuleProvider.GetModuleProvider(String userName, String connectionName)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
```

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]`.

`Process:InetMgr
Connection:CORP\hg185024`

Comment: Are you on a Windows Server when seeing this error?

Comment: yes. windows server 2012